# Vba Loop to delete rows with numeric value in Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete any row with a numeric value in a cell. When I run the following code it correctly evaluates the IsEmpty and IsNumeric() functions and deletes the row. However it stops for some reason and will complete after 3 tries. Note: I've tried Cell.Value and Cell.Value2.

```
For Each Cell In Range("H1:H600")
    If Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then
        If IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: when deleting go from the bottom up, you'll get much more consistent results.

Comment: that's because when you delete a row, the other rows get bumped up. If you delete 1 reduce i by `i=i-1`

Comment: You need to loop backwards or it will skip lines.  See here for three options; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing rows without skipping a row how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683107/removing-rows-without-skipping-a-row-how-to)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have formulas in that range:

```
Range("H1:H600").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: I was thinking the same but some of his numbers might be stored as text

Comment: That will also remove any numbers formatted as text

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. This worked and is obviously a lot fast than what I had. Thanks